# Получение подстроки из адреса электронной почты

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть строка(e-mail) `petr.petrov@gmail.com` . Из нее надо получить `PetrPetrov`. При этом в исходной строке может быть любой регистр у всех букв(все маленькие, все большие, 1 буквы в имени и фамилии - большие, остальные - маленькие и т.д.)

Сделал сейчас так

```
my_str='petr.petrov@gmail.com'

print(' '.join(my_str.lower().split('@')[0].split('.')).title().replace(' ', ''))
```

Но может есть какой более подходящий способ?

Comment: `my_str.title().split('@')[0]`

Comment: @S.Nick получается `title()` меняет регистр 1 буквы после любого символа кроме буквы?

Comment: Функция `title` - это строковый метод Python, который используется для преобразования первого символа в каждом слове в верхний регистр, а оставшиеся символы в нижний регистр в строке и возвращает новую строку.

Comment: @S.Nick ну я так понимаю что в данном понятии слово это любой набор букв разделенный чем угодно кроме буквы.

Comment: @S.Nick еще `.replace('.', '')` в конце наверное, чтобы как у ТЗ без точки было

Comment: `'petr.petrov@gmail.com-asAA,qwAAA_asASDF'.title()`

Comment: `.replace('.', '')` - да